# x86_64-binfmt-P: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, conda, arm64

I am a new user of arm64 raspberry pi plateform.
when i try to build a file by the make command the following error occurs:

x86_64-binfmt-P: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory

Thank yo for your suggestions.

Comment: You're trying to run a binary for the wrong architecture.

Comment: how could i run binary for arm64 architecture ? what the library should be installed to do this?